# How do I use realm with react-native correctly?

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I have a "small" problem trying to use realm in combination with my react-native app.
I just started with react native and I have installed and updated everything I need for development.

I installed first realm with the command

```
npm install realm
```

after that I followed the tutorial given by [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/).
But all I get is this error:

```
Unexpected identifier 'realm'. Expected ';' after variable declaration
```

After that I tried to look at a template provided by @realm/react.
I installed it and started to build the aplication on my phone via react-native run-android

But I get the exact same error without changing anything.
does realm only work with a specific version of react-native?
or am I doing somthing wrong?

I am getting that error even by just declaring a scheme.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity,ScrollView, Image, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets, CardStyleInterpolators } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Icon, Button } from "@rneui/themed";
import { styles } from './CSS/style';
import Realm from "realm";

const TaskSchema = {
  name: "Task",
  properties: {
    _id: "int",
    name: "string",
    status: "string?",
  },
  primaryKey: "_id",
};
```

Comment: Did you inspect the first line of code in the question `import React, { useState } from 'react';` to ensure there are no typographical errors and that code compiles?

Comment: The code works fine without the real plugin. Is there a typo in that line? If so I am unable to see it?

Comment: Not necessarily. I was suggesting going through each line to determine where the issue is. You need to have React Native v0.31.0. Have you ensured that the sample provided in the React install works? [React](https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html). Then, ensure your run `npm start`. Also, don't forget to [Open The Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/quick-start-local/#open-a-realm)